# Find the point on the curve where it is a curvature maximum

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, curves

> Find the curvature of the curve $\overrightarrow r(t)=2t \overrightarrow i +t^2\overrightarrow j + \frac{t^3}{3}\overrightarrow k$.  At what point on that curve is curvature maximum?

I found the curvature to be:

$\frac{6}{(t^2+2)^3}$

From here, how do I find the curvature maximum?  I assumed I would set the curvature equal to $0$ but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: For what value of $t$ is $6/(t^{2} + 2)^{3}$ largest? This doesn't even require calculus. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\kappa(t) = \frac{6}{(t^2+2)^3}$, we want to find $t$ where $\kappa(t)$ takes a maximum value. We want to set the $derivative$ equal to zero. We get:

$$ \kappa '(t) = \frac{-36t}{(t^2+2)^4} = 0$$

This is only true when $t=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  It seems to weird to me that the maximum occurs at $t=0$, which means the point was be $(0,0,0)$

Comment: Yep, that's right.  If you want an inuitive sense of what this looks like, try a 3-D graphing tool.  You'll see it's the bends most sharply at the origin.